# Is it possible to suppress all frame titles in beamer?

Tags: beamer, presentations

I would like to know if there is a `beamer` option to suppress all frame titles.

I suspect not, since this may seem like an odd thing to do.  The reason I want to do it is because I have to make two versions of a presentation -- one standard version, and one version with no frame titles, no margins, and possibly larger font.  (I will import the second version into Prezi.)

I am using an ifthen boolean to compile one or the other version, so I suppose I could start each frame as follows:

```
\ifthenelse{\boolean{prezi}}{
\begin{frame}{} % no frame title
}{
\begin{frame}{Here is my frame title}
}
```

but that seems a bit tedious.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set the `frametitle` template to nothing:

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test Frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Commenting out the line `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{}` you'll get the titles back.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks!!  Now I can just use one ifthen command with `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{}` inside.