# Single line beamer slide

Tags: beamer, spacing

This probably isn't how beamer is intended to be used.

However, I would like to create a beamer slide where:

- there is only a single line in the slide/frame
- the single line is vertically and horizontally centered
- the single line has the exact same style as the frame title

  I'm using `\usetheme{default}` so there's no magic going on. (The frametitle is just some font in a light blue color.)

  What is the dumbest way I can achieve this? (I see that there are "title slides" -- but I want many of them, and I don't want the author part. I see also that I can use `\frametitle` in a frame ... but it's stuck at the top of the frame.)

  I'm looking for something that's equiv to:

  ```
  \newpage
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \hspace*{\fill}...\hspace*{\fill}\vspace*{\fill}
  \newpage
  ```

but in beamer.

Comment: How did you fix the code? I could have sworn I put in 4 spaces before each line.

Comment: Is the sidebar wrong? Do we need 8 spaces?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.


A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user31648".

Comment: @user31648 if the code follows immediately after a list, eight spaces are required.

Comment: You should all upvote my question so I have enough reputation to accept an answer. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `frametitle` font and color; by default the text will be vertically centered, so you only have to add `\centering` to center the text horizontally:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test frame}
\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}
\centering
A line of text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is almost what I want. How do I get rid of the "test frame"? If I use \frametitle{}, it just uses the first word of my slide as the title.

Comment: To be precise, I want the "a line of text" to stay as it is, and the "Test frame" to vanish.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56717/is-it-possible-to-suppress-all-frame-titles-in-beamer is what I need.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you want (essentially combining both of Gonzalo's answers together):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{}
\newenvironment{myline}
  {\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}\vfill\centering}
  {\par\vfill}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\begin{myline}
This is a single line of text.
\end{myline}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Yes, this is basically what I ended up hacking together using both posts. Thanks! :-)